# My app keeps crashing when I press the button to return to the activity from a dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

The issue stems from the OK Button clickable. the moment I click on the button (in both cases of text and numbers being present/absent in the EditTexts) the app stops working. I can't seem to find where this error is coming from. I've double-checked variables being initialized and the problem doesn't seem to stem from there. Can anyone help out?

The code is below:

```
public void mInput(View view){
     final Dialog dialogManualInput = new Dialog(this);
     dialogManualInput.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_A);
     dialogManualInput.setTitle("Title");

     et1 = (EditText) dialogManualInput.findViewById(R.id.item);
     et2 = (EditText) dialogManualInput.findViewById(R.id.price);
     et3 = (EditText) dialogManualInput.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

     m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_A,m_listItems);
     checkoutList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
     checkoutList.setAdapter(m_adapter);

     dialogManualInput.show();

     Button okButton = (Button) dialogManualInput.findViewById(R.id.ok);
     okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        String input_1 = et1.getText().toString();
        String input_2 = et2.getText().toString();
        String input_3 = et3.getText().toString();
        int int_1 = Integer.valueOf(et3);
        int int_2 = Integer.valueOf(et2);
        String input = "("+et2+")  " + et1 +"   "+ (int_1*int_2);
        if((null!=input_1)&&(null!=input_2)&&(null!=input_3)){
           m_listItems.add(input);
           m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        dialogManualInput.dismiss();
      }
  });
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
09-23 23:56:01.793    7464-7464/com.kwesimbia.management E/ArrayAdapter? You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
09-23 23:56:01.803    7464-7464/com.kwesimbia.management D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
09-23 23:56:01.803    7464-7464/com.kwesimbia.management W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a99228)
09-23 23:56:01.843    7464-7464/com.kwesimbia.management E/AndroidRuntime?   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2046)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1820)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1876)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2498)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
        ... 33 more
  09-23 23:56:01.873     239-1201/? E/EmbeddedLogger? App crashed! Process: com.kwesimbia.management
  09-23 23:56:01.873     239-1201/? E/EmbeddedLogger? App crashed! Package:    com.kwesimbia.management v1 (1.0)
  09-23 23:56:01.873     239-1201/? E/EmbeddedLogger? Application Label: abaawa
  09-23 23:56:01.873     239-1201/? W/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity          com.kwesimbia.management/.ArtActivity
```

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: I've edited and included the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

As it seems from Logcat problem is

```
 m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_A,m_listItems);
 checkoutList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
 checkoutList.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

You are providing m_listItems(I don't know what this is ) and
its is looking for an id of a **TextView** pass a textView's ID in

```
 ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_A,m_listItems);
```

Some thing like

```
 ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_A,R.id.textView01);
```

---

Probable Errors

what is this doing you directly putting your edittext to be concatenated with string what it is expected to here may be it should be **int_1**, or **et1.getText()** i.e. **input_1**

```
    String input = "("+et2+")  " + et1 +"   "+ (int_1*int_2);
```

If any not initialized as usual **NPE** for et1, et2, et3
OR

Parsing Exception in these (if you not fill the editText then it must throw exception)

```
    int int_1 = Integer.valueOf(et3);
    int int_2 = Integer.valueOf(et2);
```

Comment: What I intended to do with this was pass the text from the editTexts into a ListView

Comment: @user2766109 Check edit 1 only you are passing layout id but it should be TextView id in your list view

Comment: @user2766109 Everything is OK just edit your Adapter pass text view id from the layout it will show as your expected resutl

Comment: I've tried some level of testing and it seems this line of code is the main reason for the crash:  <br/> `m_listItems.add(input);`

Comment: No mate as i said change your id otherwise you will remain puzzled at this line it tries to add text which calls adapter to bind the text with ListView's TextView which pick the id from the id you given which is a layout not text You must be having a ListView's Layout in which there could be a TextView which you should provide as an id but you give Layouts id which is totally wrong causes crash and if you don;t believe do what ever you want

Comment: @user2766109 I updated the answer I was lil confused with layout but its your last parameter **m_listItems** I don't know what this is but it is expected to be the id of a text view

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with your layout. Show us this XML file "R.layout.activity_A" or take a look at it.